# Unable to play Multiple Audio files using Latest Exoplayer(2.18.1) in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer, audio-player, exoplayer2.x

I want to implement the Simple App that can play multiple asset audio files together.

same as [soft sound](https://github.com/wildeyedskies/Soft-Sound) but with the latest build gradle of Exoplayer i.e, 2.18.1

it has only two kt classes [MainActivity.kt](https://github.com/wildeyedskies/Soft-Sound/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/mcxa/softsound/MainActivity.kt), [PlayerService.kt](https://github.com/wildeyedskies/Soft-Sound/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/mcxa/softsound/PlayerService.kt)

but most of the used ExoPlayer classes were deprecated in it.

`PlyerService.kt`

```kotlin
 private fun initializeExoPlayer(soundFile: String): SimpleExoPlayer {
        // create the player
        val exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(
                DefaultRenderersFactory(this), DefaultTrackSelector()
        )

        // load the media source
        val dataSource = DefaultDataSourceFactory(this,
                Util.getUserAgent(this, this.getString(R.string.app_name)))
        val mediaSource = ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSource)
                .createMediaSource(Uri.parse("asset:///$soundFile"))

        // load the media
        Log.d("MAIN", "loading $soundFile")
        exoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource)
        // loop indefinitely
        exoPlayer.repeatMode = Player.REPEAT_MODE_ALL

        return exoPlayer
    }
```

USING

```
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.8.4'
```

```
                                   **TRIED**
```

managed to omit flashing errors by changing the function into

```kotlin
 private fun initializeExoPlayer(soundFile: String): ExoPlayer {

       
        // create the player
        val trackSelector = DefaultTrackSelector(this)
        val exoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Builder(this).setTrackSelector(trackSelector).build()

        // load the media source
        val dataSource = DefaultDataSource.Factory(this)
        val mediaSource = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSource)
            .createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(Uri.parse("asset:///$soundFile")))

        // load the media
        Log.d("MAIN", "loading $soundFile")
        exoPlayer.setMediaSource(mediaSource)
        exoPlayer.prepare()
        exoPlayer.play()
        // loop indefinitely
        exoPlayer.repeatMode = Player.REPEAT_MODE_ALL

        return exoPlayer
    }
```

using

```
api "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.18.1"
```

all deprecated indications errors were gone but **NO MEDIA IS PLAYING**

Please guide me on how to change the upper function correctly
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: tried Documentation but Exoplayer Documentation is very hard to understand

Comment: The exoplayer documentation is actually very good, but you will need a good understanding of terms used. I found that playing around with the demo app (clone the project and open it in android studio) really helped my understanding. I suggest starting here. It is a complex topic and does take some time to grasp.

Comment: It seems `DefaultDataSource.Factory` doesn't use `Util.getUserAgent` as opposed to `DefaultDataSourceFactory ` . Is it true? No need to use this function anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking the code that you have shared with me. You need to add a `PlayerService` class in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
<service
            android:name=".PlayerService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />
```