# Type mismatch: inferred type is String but DataSource.Factory was expected

Tags: kotlin, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x, exoplayer-media-item

Type mismatch: inferred type is String but DataSource.Factory was expected

```
 private fun initializeExoPlayer(soundFile: String): ExoPlayer {

        // create the player
        val trackSelector = DefaultTrackSelector(this)
        val exoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Builder(this).setTrackSelector(trackSelector).build()

        // load the media source
        val dataSource = DefaultDataSource.Factory(this,
            Util.getUserAgent(this, this.getString(R.string.app_name)))

        val mediaSource = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSource)
            .createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(Uri.parse("asset:///$soundFile")))

        // load the media
        Log.d("MAIN", "loading $soundFile")
        //exoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource)
        exoPlayer.prepare()
        // loop indefinitely
        exoPlayer.repeatMode = Player.REPEAT_MODE_ALL

        return exoPlayer
    }
```

[image: error screenshot]

error is gone when using
(deprecated) DefaultDataSourceFactory instead of DefaultDataSource.Factory
And
no media is playing

Comment: Can you show us at least the signature of `Util.getUserAgent`?

Comment: hii @LouisWasserman Sir, what it's signature, or how to know its signature

Comment: The first line, like `private fun initializeExoPlayer(soundFile: String): ExoPlayer`

Comment: @LouisWasserman Sir, here is my minimal [PlayerService.kt](https://github.com/th3kumar/Snoozz-Sleeping-Buddy/blob/master/app/src/main/java/PlayerService.kt) file.

Comment: I mean, it looks pretty self explanatory.  `DefaultDataSource.Factory`'s constructor expects a `DataSource.Factory`, and you've passed it a `String` instead.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Sir, hope you are well, can you guide me on how to change this `String` to `DataSource.Factory` .

Comment: @LouisWasserman please look into this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74084346/unable-to-play-multiple-audio-files-using-latest-exoplayer2-18-1-in-kotlin)